# T-SQL logic for roll up and group by

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, data-warehouse

I have a question to collapse or roll up data based on the logic below.
How can I implement it?

The logic that allows episodes to be condensed into a single continuous care episode is a discharge code of 22 followed by an admission code of 4 on the same day.

[image: continuous care implementation][continuous care implementation update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK2Uk.png)

EPN--is a business_key.

episode_continuous_care_key is an artificial key that can be a row number function.

Below is the table structure.

```
            drop table #source
            CREATE TABLE #source(patidid varchar(20),epn int,preadmitdate datetime,adminttime varchar(10),
            admitcode varchar(10),datedischarge datetime,disctime varchar(10),disccode varchar(10))
            INSERT INTO #source VALUES
             (1849,1,'4/23/2020','7:29',1,'7/31/2020','9:03',22)
            ,(1849,2,'7/31/2020','11:00',4,'7/31/2020','12:09',22)
            ,(1849,3,'7/31/2020','13:10',4,'8/24/2020','10:36',10)
            ,(1849,4,'8/26/2020','12:25',2,null,null,null)
            ,(1850,1,'4/23/2020','7:33',1,'6/29/2020','7:30',22)
            ,(1850,2,'6/29/2020','9:35',4,'7/8/2020','10:51',7)
            ,(1850,3,'7/10/2020','11:51',3,'7/29/2020','9:12',7)
            ,(1850,4,'7/31/2020','11:00',2,'8/6/2020','10:24',22)
            ,(1850,5,'8/6/2020','12:26',4,null,null,null)
            ,(1851,1,'4/23/2020','7:35',1,'6/24/2020','13:45',22)
            ,(1851,2,'6/24/2020','15:06',4,'9/24/2020','15:00',2)
            ,(1851,3,'12/4/2020','8:59',0,null,null,null)
            ,(1852,1,'4/23/2020','7:37',1,'7/6/2020','11:15',20)
            ,(1852,2,'7/8/2020','10:56',0,'7/10/2020','11:46',2)
            ,(1852,3,'7/10/2020','11:47',2,'7/28/2020','13:16',22)
            ,(1852,4,'7/28/2020','15:17',4,'8/4/2020','11:37',22)
            ,(1852,5,'8/4/2020','13:40',4,'11/18/2020','15:43',2)
            ,(1852,6,'12/2/2020','15:23',2,null,null,null)
            ,(1853,1,'4/23/2020','7:40',1,'7/1/2020','8:30',22)
            ,(1853,2,'7/1/2020','14:57',4,'12/4/2020','12:55',7)
            ,(1854,1,'4/23/2020','7:44',1,'7/31/2020','13:07',20)
            ,(1854,2,'8/3/2020','16:30',0,'8/5/2020','9:32',2)
            ,(1854,3,'8/5/2020','10:34',2,'8/24/2020','8:15',22)
            ,(1854,4,'8/24/2020','10:33',4,'12/4/2020','7:30',22)
            ,(1854,5,'12/4/2020','9:13',4,null,null,null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Excel sheet image says little about your database design so I invented my own version that more or less resembles your image. With a proper database design the first step of the solution should not be required...

1. Unpivot timestamp information so that admission timestamp and discharge timestamps become one column.
   *I used a common table expression `Log1` for this action.*
2. Use the codes to filter out the start of the continuous care periods. Those are the admissions, marked with `Code.IsAdmission = 1` in my database design.
   Also add the next period start as another column by using the `lead()` function.
   *These are all the actions from `Log2`.*
3. Add a row number as continuous care key.
   Using the next period start date, find the current continuous period end date with a `cross apply`.
   Replace empty period end dates with the current date using the `coalesce()` function.
   Calculate the difference as the continuous care period duration with the `datediff()` function.

**Sample data**

```
create table Codes
(
  Code int,
  Description nvarchar(50),
  IsAdmission bit
);

insert into Codes (Code, Description, IsAdmission) values
( 1, 'First admission', 1),
( 2, 'Re-admission', 1),
( 4, 'Campus transfer IN', 0),
(10, 'Trial visit', 0),
(22, 'Campus transfer OUT', 0);

create table PatientLogs
(
  PatientId int,
  AdmitDateTime smalldatetime,
  AdmitCode int,
  DischargeDateTime smalldatetime,
  DischargeCode int
);

insert into PatientLogs (PatientId, AdmitDateTime, AdmitCode, DischargeDateTime, DischargeCode) values
(1849, '2020-04-23 07:29', 1, '2020-07-31 09:03', 22),
(1849, '2020-07-31 11:00', 4, '2020-07-31 12:09', 22),
(1849, '2020-07-31 13:10', 4, '2020-08-24 10:36', 10),
(1849, '2020-08-26 12:25', 2, null, null);
```

**Solution**

```
with Log1 as
(
  select updt.PatientId,
         case updt.DateTimeType
           when 'AdmitDateTime' then updt.AdmitCode
           when 'DischargeDateTime' then updt.DischargeCode
         end as Code,
         updt.LogDateTime,
         updt.DateTimeType
  from PatientLogs pl
  unpivot (LogDateTime for DateTimeType in (AdmitDateTime, DischargeDateTime)) updt
),
Log2 as (
  select l.PatientId,
         l.Code,
         l.LogDateTime,
         lead(l.LogDateTime) over(partition by l.PatientId order by l.LogDateTime) as LogDateTimeNext
  from Log1 l
  join Codes c
    on c.Code = l.Code
  where c.IsAdmission = 1
)
select la.PatientId,
       row_number() over(partition by la.PatientId order by la.LogDateTime) as ContCareKey,
       la.LogDateTime as AdmitDateTime,
       coalesce(ld.LogDateTime, convert(smalldatetime, getdate())) as DischargeDateTime,
       datediff(day, la.LogDateTime, coalesce(ld.LogDateTime, convert(smalldatetime, getdate()))) as ContStay
from Log2 la -- log admission
outer apply ( select top 1 l1.LogDateTime
              from Log1 l1
              where l1.PatientId = la.PatientId
                and l1.LogDateTime < la.LogDateTimeNext
              order by l1.LogDateTime desc ) ld -- log discharge
order by la.PatientId,
         la.LogDateTime;
```

**Result**

```
PatientId  ContCareKey  AdmitDateTime     DischargeDateTime  ContStay
---------  -----------  ----------------  -----------------  --------
1849       1            2020-04-23 07:29  2020-08-24 10:36   123
1849       2            2020-08-26 12:25  2021-02-03 12:49   161
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=8e748cb924375943260885fc7abef888) to see things in action with intermediate results.

Comment: .I appreciate your solution.I have also updated the original question and included both table structure and desired result.The code consist of more it we could work the solution out of  a single table that will be great

Answer (score 0):

Here is a T-SQL solution that contains primary and foreign key relationships.

To make it a bit more realistic, I added a simple "Patient" table.

I put all your "codes" into a single table which should make it easier to manage the codes.

I do not understand the purpose of your concept of "continuous care" so I just added an "is first" binary column to the Admission table.
You might also consider adding something about the medical condition for which the patient is being treated.

[image: Codes schema]

```
    CREATE SCHEMA Codes
GO

GO


CREATE TABLE dbo.Code
(
    codeNr int NOT NULL,
    description nvarchar(50),
    CONSTRAINT Code_PK PRIMARY KEY(codeNr)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE dbo.Patient
(
    patientNr int NOT NULL,
    birthDate date NOT NULL,
    firstName nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    lastName nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Patient_PK PRIMARY KEY(patientNr)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE dbo.Admission
(
    admitDateTime time NOT NULL,
    patientNr int NOT NULL,
    admitCode int,
    isFirst bit,
    CONSTRAINT Admission_PK PRIMARY KEY(patientNr, admitDateTime)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE dbo.Discharge
(
    dischargeDateTime time NOT NULL,
    patientNr int NOT NULL,
    dischargeCode int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Discharge_PK PRIMARY KEY(patientNr, dischargeDateTime)
)
GO


ALTER TABLE dbo.Admission ADD CONSTRAINT Admission_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (patientNr) REFERENCES dbo.Patient (patientNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE dbo.Admission ADD CONSTRAINT Admission_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (admitCode) REFERENCES dbo.Code (codeNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE dbo.Discharge ADD CONSTRAINT Discharge_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (patientNr) REFERENCES dbo.Patient (patientNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE dbo.Discharge ADD CONSTRAINT Discharge_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (dischargeCode) REFERENCES dbo.Code (codeNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


GO
```

Comment: continuous care episode is a discharge code of 22 followed by an admission code of 4 on the same day.Because the patient was just transferred from 1 care to another especially when it happens on the same day.So the goal is to consider it as 1 episode rather than 2 episode hence 1 continuous length of stay.I have also updated the original question and included both table structure and desired result.

Comment: I really do appreciate your solution but if you could assist with the table definition I provided and the intended result that will be more helpful to me.Thanks

Comment: "Continuous care episode" 
Yes I understood your idea of using codes but the codes themselves are meaningless. They are just numbers that someone has decided to use to classify a state of affairs in the real world. My question was about the state of affairs, not about the code numbers..
I don't know what you mean by "table definition and intended result."  You can use simple SQL queries to get the result that you want..
 Are you saying that you don't understand SQL?

Comment: I understand SQL codes.You indicated initially that the excel said little about the database design so I uploaded the original post and included that.That was what I meant by" table definition & intended result"..The codes are more than what was shown in the excel.It is about 7 codes for admit and 34 codes for discharge .The only code that relate both fields is the code 22 with value = continuous transfer in discharge while it is = 4 in admit

Comment: Maybe what I should have started by saying is that you seem to be creating unnecessary complexity by trying to use a spreadsheet for work that should be done in a relational database management system such as SQL Server.
What you call "codes" have nothing to do with SQL.
My design will allow you to use any number of numeric codes and to extract the information that you need by using a simple SQL query.